# Set dynamically generated buttons "disabled"

Tags: javascript, jquery, prop

I have a chat application based on WebSockets. Next to every message there should be a rating button. I need to prohibit selfratings by setting the corresponting buttons to disabled. The problem is that the messages and their buttons are generated dynamically and the code snippet doesn't work.

```js
$(".btn").prop("disabled", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: Your snippet is throwing a 500 internal server error...

Comment: @MTCoster the site has some problems, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284780/code-snippet-execution-window-returns-server-error

Comment: Dont forget to put a sanity check on server side.... Its very easy to make the button enabled.  :)

Answer (score 2):

you have to call the

```
$(".btn").prop("disabled", true);
```

right after the dynamic generated html snippet is inserted into the DOM-Tree.

or you add the disabled right on the generation of the html node.

```
<button class="btn" disabled>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/172/

```
<button class="add">Add</button>
<div class="section" id="template">
    This is a section
    <button class="rate">Rate This!</button>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var clone = $('#template').clone(true).attr('id', '');
        clone.find('.rate').prop('disabled', true);
        clone.appendTo('body');        
    });
});
```